# Using the camera inside an Android app

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview

I want to create an Android app which uses a camera, but I don't want the app to redirect to the default camera app on the device.

I want a custom-made camera app specifically for the app. How do I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Look into this tutorial http://www.airpair.com/android/android-camera-surface-view-fragment

[Link 2](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html)

you can use SurfaceView Fragment.

Comment: accept the answer if it worked for you  and voteup if possible... Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice tutorial to accomplish it.

[Camera Integration with Surface View](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-use-android-camera-to-take.html)

You can make your custom changes on the SurfaceView according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I used https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera to get custom camera done.

The library @commonsware made, great library with great documentation and support.